# C can pointers be aligned with any other data type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-alignment

I've implemented a jagged multi-dimensional array by allocating the space for the intermediate arrays *as well as* the actual elements in **1** large block. While working on this I figured I had to take into account the alignment of the elements being stored, just in case. But I'm not sure if this safety check is needed, so I've come to ask: Would the size of a pointer keep things aligned for any other type?

In short: Given a contiguous memory space *from a call to malloc* that looks like:

```
| ARRAY OF POINTERS | ALIGN PADDING | ARRAY OF AN ARBITRARY ELEMENT TYPE |
```

Do I really *need* the padding here when the first array is made of pointers? Are there cases where the padding is necessary?

Comment: `Would the size of a pointer keep things aligned for any other type?` It's true in most cases, but I'm curious whether it's guaranteed by standard C or not. +1

Comment: You may have 32bits pointers, while storing 64bits values... With an odd number of values, padding is definitely needed.

Comment: You shouldn't "need" padding beyond what's required to align to the word size of your CPU. You might get a slight speedup by aligning things on a larger boundary though.

Comment: @MarkRansom True on x86, but some architectures requires values to be aligned.

Comment: @Macmade which architecture requires alignment beyond the word size?

Comment: @MarkRansom SSE Instructions on X86??  Depending on the instruction, it could require 64 or 128 bit alignment

Comment: @8bitwide thanks for the example, I retract my comment.

Comment: IMO: either use a struct that contains the whole data scheme -or- use separate malloc statements for the separate data groups.  With out an overriding reason for trying to compress it all together, like using a 16bit cpu and need to save every byte possible, it is far better to not pack together unrelated data

Comment: Thanks for the help and specific example! Also @user the reason for compressing it together is that it allows my function to create dynamic arrays (arr[m][n][o]...) with a single malloc instead of m\*n\*o\*... calls.

Comment: Why not make a union of all the types you are concerned with and align to the sizeof the union?

Comment: What do you need this sort of structure for? The pointers are redundant as the data can be found by calculating offsets

Comment: @Matt I use it for a dynamic multi-dimensional array. Here is my code: https://github.com/thatbrod/scripts/blob/master/contiguous_mdim_array.c

Comment: You know you can have a contiguous multidimensional array without having a bunch of pointers on the front, right

Comment: @Matt If you mean statically, yeah. But dynamically, I haven't found a way to do that, do you have an example?

Comment: `T (*ptr)[dim2][dim3] = malloc( dim1 * sizeof *ptr );`.  You can cast to `void *` for purposes of returning from a function.  There are a few use cases for your layout (e.g. if you have to call a third party function that only wants jagged arrays) but it seems many people don't know about using non-constant values in array dimensions and/or pointers to array type

Comment: Nope I had no clue! Ahh I don't know how I missed this I searched for a while on better ways to get this working... thanks a lot for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard doesn't explicitly guarantee that object pointers have the most stringent alignment requirements.  On some systems, `long double` may have a more stringent alignment requirement; on other systems, function pointers may have a more stringent alignment requirement.

However, with a little care and attention, you can determine the alignment requirements.  You need to decide how portable and automatic you need the answer to be.  It is easy to find an answer by compiling code and finding the answer.  It is considerably harder to create a foolproof automatic way of doing it automatically for any type, not least because the arbitrary element type may be larger or smaller than an object pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified all the necessary details required in order to answer this question.

So here is an example where padding is necessary:

```
struct Element
{
    unsigned long long x;
    ...
};

void* ptrArray[TOTAL_SIZE];
```

If you are running on a 32-bit platform **AND** you have defined an odd number of pointers, then you will need a 4-byte padding in order to ensure the alignment of the 8-byte variable at the beginning of each element.

In addition, please note that if you want to store more than a single element in the array, then the size of the element type itself must be a multiple of 8 bytes in order for this to work.

If you wish to avoid padding altogether, then you will have to `memcpy` an element from and into the array every time you need to access (read or write) that specific element.